# Extract href from html page using php

Tags: php, html, parsing

I trying to extract the news headlines and the link (href) of each headline using the code bellow, but the link extraction is not working. It's only getting the headline. Please help me find out what's wrong with the code.

Link to page from which I want to get the headline and link from:
http://web.tmxmoney.com/news.php?qm_symbol=BCM

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://web.tmxmoney.com/news.php?qm_symbol=BCM');
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$rows = $xpath->query('//div');

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('span');

    $newstitle = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $link = $cols->item(0)->nodeType === HTML_ELEMENT_NODE ? $cols->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href') : '';

echo $newstitle . '<br>';
echo $link . '<br><br>';
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
<?php
  $data= file_get_contents('http://web.tmxmoney.com/news.php?qm_symbol=BCM');

  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($data);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $hrefs= $xpath->query('/html/body//a');

  for($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++){
   $href = $hrefs->item($i);
   $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
   $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

   if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false){
      echo '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a><br />';
   }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks allot for answering. Your code echos some links from the web page, but they don't belong to the headlines (news releases). The code I pasted in my question echos all news (headlines), but no links of respective headline. I tried to play around with your code (inclunding changing the $hrefs, but it didn't work). Please try again when you have enough time. Thanks again!

Comment: I am sorry, but i cant access to the webpage so i can´t test the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Here it goes:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://web.tmxmoney.com/news.php?qm_symbol=BCM');
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$rows = $xpath->query('//div');

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    $cols1 = $row->getElementsByTagName('a');

    $link = $cols1->item(0)->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE ? $cols1->item(0)->getAttribute('href') : '';

    $cols2 = $row->getElementsByTagName('span');

    $title = $cols2->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $source = $cols2->item(1)->nodeValue;

echo $title . '<br>';
echo $source . '<br>';
echo $link . '<br><br>';

}
?>
```